# How to extract string with regex in Velocity?

Tags: regex, velocity

We have confluence docs portal where we use the **Scroll Viewport** plugin. This plugin uses **Velocity** as a template language. I need to get, that highlighted, string from a URL. I already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477518/output-part-of-a-string-in-velocity) on SO but it does not work for me. I tried it with using regex because I thought is the best solution.

www.servename.com/home/display/**DOCMS**/Tracking+Data+and+System+Errors

What I did so far:

```
 #set($regex = "s/.*\/\/.*\/.*\/.*\/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/")
 #set($url = $result.absoluteLink)
 #set($spaceName = $url.replaceAll($regex, ""))
 $spaceName
```

Comment: For starters, your regex requires the protocol portion of the uri, followed by a //.  Not sure if that is your ultimate answer, and I was looking something similar.  Also, I think you need to reference the () portion as your second argument to the replaceAll($regex, "$1")