# Pass Java function in Velocity template

Tags: java, velocity, vtl

I'm stuck on this.

```
public String getMessage(String id)
{
    log.error("passing parameter "+id+" "+id.getClass().getName());
    if(id.compareTo("1")==0)
    {
        return "nothing perfect";
    }
    else {return "All done";}
}
```

.vm

```
#set($parameter="1")
#set($message = $action.getMessage("$parameter").show())
<td>$message</td>`
```

In the rendered HTML I get `$message`. Why am I not getting the actual message?

Comment: do "1".equals(id) instead

Comment: nothing changed

Answer (score 4):

From Velocity documentation:

> Velocity is just a façade for real Java objects...

So, to access the public methods of a class in the Velocity template, the object of the concerned class should be *visible* to the velocity template.

```
public class MessageSource {

    public String getMessage(String id){
        log.error("passing parameter "+id+" "+id.getClass().getName());
        if(id.compareTo("1")==0){
            return "nothing perfect";
        } else { 
            return "All done";
        }
    }

}
```

Now to expose the object of `MessageSource`:

```
/*  first, get and initialize an engine  */
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.init();
/*  next, get the Template  */
Template t = ve.getTemplate( "helloworld.vm" );
/*  create a context and add data */
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("messageSource", new MessageSource());
/* now render the template into a StringWriter */
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
t.merge( context, writer );
/* show the World */
System.out.println( writer.toString() );
```

So, in your velocity template...

```
$messageSource.getMessage("identifier")
```

---

- [Reference Link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html)
- [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487233/5766794)

Answer (score 3):

> You can't directly pass function in velocity.

### Test.java

```
public class Test {

    Message mg = new Message(); 
    context.put("formatter", mg);         
}
```

### Message.java

```
public class Message {

    public String getMessage(String id){
        log.error("passing parameter "+id+" "+id.getClass().getName());
        if(id.compareTo("1")==0){
            return "nothing perfect";
        } else { 
            return "All done";
        }
    }
}
```

### example.vm

```
#set($parameter="1")
#set($message = $formatter.Message($parameter))
<td>$message</td>
```

Comment: Good answer, but need explaination.